# Transactions in Dart Mysql1

Tags: dart

How do I perform a transaction in dart mysql1.
I tried doing this,

```
await pool.transactional((conn) async {});
```

But the key wait pool is showing this error
**Undefined name 'pool'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dartundefined_identifier**

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
await MySqlConnection.connect(MYSQL_SETTING).transaction((context) async {}）
```